# C malloc syntax

Tags: c, malloc, free, freeze

```
str = (char *) malloc(15);
```

If I do not type `(char *)`, is there any difference in my program?

If I try to free the memory with `free(str)`, linux freezes unexpectedly after running program.

Comment: Show us what you do with `str`. I don't see any problem with `free` so far.

Comment: I can t upload the program. I will use valgrind to track the memory error. Thanks.

Comment: That's why questions are supposed to be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Valgrind is hunting for mosquitoes with a shotgun.

Answer (score 0):

If you program in C, it does not make a difference, the preferred syntax is actually

```
char *str = malloc(15);
```

If you were programming in C++, the return value from `malloc()` would not be cast implicitly as `char *` for storing into `str`. But in C++, you should not use `malloc()` anyway, you should write `str = new char[15];` and free this memory with `delete []str;`.

A potential reason for `free(str);` to cause undefined behavior is your writing to the array pointed to by `str` beyond the first 15 bytes.

Use `valgrind` to help track down where this happens.

Comment: Thanks. I will use valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

**char *malloc(size)
unsigned size;**

malloc() is used to allocate a certain number, size, of free memory and return a pointer to the beginning of it. The malloc() function is part of the dynamic allocation routines.
    If an allocation request fails- that is, if there is insufficient memory to fill the request- a null pointer is returned.
    You always must be very careful to make sure that you receive a valid pointer from malloc().

**This is the general form of a program that will allocate 80 bytes of memory and then free them.**

```
 main()
        {
          char *p;
          p= malloc(80);
          if(!p){ printf("out of memory\n"); exit(2); }
        .
        .
        .
        free(p);
        }
```

Comment: Should use `perror` instead of `printf`  on `malloc` failure

Comment: `char *malloc(size) unsigned size;` is a pre-Ansi C prototype.  It is completely obsolete.  The standard declaration for `malloc` is `void *malloc(size_t size);`